# Django DisallowedHost error

Tags: python, django, apache

I'm running django with apache and I'm getting the following error in my apache error.log:

```
django.core.exceptions.DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'example.com'. You may need to add 'example.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS., referer: http://example.com/
```

In my settings.py I have:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

This should allow any host shouldn't it?

Edit:
After some more investigating I've found out that no matter what I set ALLOWED_HOSTS to, it always results in the above error. I can reach the website just fine when I'm using the local IP address of the server. The only thing that's not working is the remote URL.

Comment: You should add your solution as a separate answer then choose it. I had the same problem, and this answer was helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution to the problem.

The wsgi.py that's connecting django with apache was overriding the ALLOWED_HOSTS setting in my settings.py.

wsgi has it's own ALLOWED_HOSTS that can be set independently from the django settings. Checking all the possible configuration files was crucial for finding this error.

Comment: Can you explain what needs to be done? I can't get the idea. I checked in my wsgi.py it loads the same django settings. like `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "wisanadjango.settings")`

Answer (score 1):

just add the url to ALLOWED_HOSTS:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['ip.ip.ip.ip', '.example.com', '127.0.0.1']
```

Comment: I've added the url, but nothing changed. I'm still getting the DisallowedHost error. :/

Comment: @henne90gen: I've had a similar issue but even after adding the host name to ALLOWED_HOSTS, it still would show the same error. In my case, I'm also running gunicorn with other virtual hosts. Of course, the error I was getting was actually coming from the other Django apps in my environment -- no way to know that though I should have known better. Once, I set up the gunicorn script for this particular app, it started working. For anyone interested, my gunicorn script looks thusly:

```gunicorn config.wsgi -b 127.0.0.1:9001 --worker-class gthread --workers 2 --threads 1 &```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I added the correct IP address in ALLOWED_HOSTS, I tried with * too and nothing worked, until I restarted the instance I was working on. Then it all worked fine.