# DisallowedHost at / even though ALLOWED_HOSTS are correct

Tags: django, nginx, deployment

I am getting the following error when navigating to the url for my test site...

[image]

My `settings.py` file looks correct...
[image]

Is there any other reason that anyone can think of why I might be getting this error? I have tried deleting all .pyc files and restarting `nginx` and tried multiple `ALLOW_HOSTS` settings.

I am using `Amazon EC2` and `Django 1.10.4`

Comment: What are you using for your wsgi (i am not sure what Amazon EC2 is)? Try resetting your wsgi. For instance, if it is gunicorn, reset that as well. I had similar issues and resetting gunicorn was the issue.

Comment: You need to restart `uwsgi` or `gunicorn`, whatever you are running. Restarting `nginx` doesn't affect that. In addition, make sure you don't have another `settings.py` file anywhere. You don't seem to be using that one since it says `DEBUG = False` but the error you showed means you have `DEBUG = True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using digital ocean I was able to fix this issue by restarting uwsgi with the following in the terminal

```
systemctl restart uwsgi.service
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem and I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40565188/django-disallowedhost-error) by George:

> "...I restarted the instance I was working on."

I am running an Ubuntu(20.04) EC2 instance on AWS.

Comment: Please provide explanation here instead of just a link.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem while using App Service.

First make sure you have defined ALLOWED_HOSTS correctly in your settings.py
If you are using environment variables, make sure to set it by going to Settings, then Configuration, then click on New Application Settings; in the Name field, set the name of the environment variable and in the Value field, set the value.

If you've done this or you didn't use environment variables, go to Overview in the menu and either Stop and Start your app or restart your app.